# What does this convenient mean?

Tags: ios, variable-assignment

```
_labelView = ({
    UIView * labelView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, _midView.frame.size.width, _midView.frame.size.height)];
    for (int i = 0;i < titleArr.count ; i++) {
        [labelView addSubview:[self returnLabel:titleArr[i] andFrame:CGRectMake(0, i*_height, self.frame.size.width, _height) andColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]];
    }
    labelView;
});
```

why "labelView" can assignment by this?

Comment: What is the declared type of `_labelView`?

Comment: I'm not sure it can or not

Comment: labelView is not what,the last line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [statement expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs), a compound statement enclosed in parentheses, used as an expression. Here is the GCC description of the pattern:

> A compound statement enclosed in parentheses may appear as an expression in GNU C. This allows you to use loops, switches, and local variables within an expression.
>
> Recall that a compound statement is a sequence of statements surrounded by braces; in this construct, parentheses go around the braces. For example:
>
> ```
> ({ int y = foo (); int z;
>     if (y > 0) z = y;
>     else z = - y;
>     z; })
> ```
>
> is a valid (though slightly more complex than necessary) expression for the absolute value of `foo ()`.
>
> The last thing in the compound statement should be an expression followed by a semicolon; the value of this subexpression serves as the value of the entire construct. (If you use some other kind of statement last within the braces, the construct has type void, and thus effectively no value.)

The most common use of statement expressions is in `#define` macros (see the [GCC discussion](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs)), and it's not often seen outside of that context.